# Define new command using \DeclareTotalTCBox in tcolorbox package

Tags: macros, tcolorbox

I have defined a command using `\DeclareTotalTCBox` command in `tcolorbox` package as blew:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\DeclareTotalTCBox{\myverb}{ O{red} v O{} }
{ fontupper=\ttfamily, nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,
leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,toprule=0.3mm,bottomrule=0.3mm,boxsep=0.5mm,
colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black,#3}{#2}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\hbox{\myverb{#1}}}
\begin{document}
Work \myverb{\LaTeX} Work
Not Working \code{\LaTeX} Not working
\end{document}
```

‎
Using `\myverb` individually works but defined command `\code` not working!!! Is there a mistake?

[image]

Comment: You are aware that there a lot of strange (but invisible) characters in your post above, which makes it hard to compile?

Comment: You cannot use `\myverb` in an argument since it contains verbatim material.

Comment: What do you want to achieve at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer i want to define new command as ``\myverb`` command.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina So we can not do something like i have did? Is there any way?

Comment: @MathMan No. At least no, with your current approach. If you tell use in detail what are you trying to achieve, we could suggest you an alternative. What exactly do you want your `\code` command to do?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I think it is clear what i want! I want to instead of using ``\hbox{\myverb{\Latex}}``, use ``\code{\Latex}`` that have same result. How can i do this?

Comment: @MathMan: Why do you insist on the `\hbox`? As `\DeclareTotalTCBox` is basically something like `\NewDocumentCommand` (from `xparse` package) you are already provided with a verbatim code 'displaying' box which can be used inline.